# Moment isBetween(hours) gives unexpected result

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm trying to get if given date is in between to dates (PM and AM).

Example input:

```
moment('22:00', 'HH:mm').isBetween(moment('17:00', 'HH:mm'),moment('01:00', 'HH:mm'));
```

I'm expecting output to be true but its false. If I'm using only PM hours or only AM hours its working perfectly.

Also tried this format but result is same

```
moment('17:00 PM', 'HH:mm A')
```

Comment: The issue is likely related to the times crossing day boundaries.

Comment: You're not adding dates, so it's like saying, is 22 between 17 and 1... the answer is no.  Something you can do is to add one day to the second time if it's lower than the "start" time. Considering you will always have a start and end time.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a moment, if the date is omitted, it will always default to the current day, so basically what you're asking is:

> Is 22:00 today between 17:00 today and 01:00 today?

The answer is, of course, no.

If you expected the `01:00` to be in the following day, either use a format that includes the date or add a day to that especific object:

```
moment('06/04/2021 22:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm').isBetween(moment('06/04/2021 17:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm'),moment('06/05/2021 01:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm'));
moment('22:00', 'HH:mm').isBetween(moment('17:00', 'HH:mm'),moment('01:00', 'HH:mm').add(1, 'day'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This a quick and dirty implementation, but it works if you accept that there will always be times passed in HH:mm:

```js
let time1 = '17:00';
let time2 = '1:00';

function isBetweenTime(timeToEvaluate, startTime, endTime){
    let momentTimeToEvaluate = moment(timeToEvaluate, "HH:mm");
  let momentStartTime = moment(startTime, "HH:mm");
  let momentEndTime = moment(endTime, "HH:mm");
  
  if(startTime > endTime){
    momentEndTime.add(1, 'days');
  }
  
  return momentTimeToEvaluate.isBetween(momentStartTime, momentEndTime);
}

console.log(isBetweenTime('22:00', time1, time2));
console.log(isBetweenTime('22:00', time2, time1));
```